# print to a "physical printer"?

Tags: windows-7, printer

A web sitewants me to print to a physical printer... How can they know if i'm using a real, physical printer or just OneNote? (BTW, they only know about your default...here is the site i'm talking about... [image: here is the site i'm talking about...]

How can I get around this?  How can I have a fake "physical printer?" in other words... can I have a virtual printer that acts like a physical one?

Comment: that is downright creepy! Applets should not be able to check your printer settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page uses a Java applet, which probably has some way of getting printer details. Java being cross-platform, it probably just checks for "OneNote" in the printer's name, so try renaming the printer. But it *could* be that the checks are more advanced.

In any case, you can install printers that are not connected – can't remember exactly how, but the "Add printer" program should offer this option. Once you have a "real" printer, existing or not, the Print dialog should have a checkbox named ["Print to file"](http://filext.com/faq/print_from_prn_file.php). What would otherwise be sent to a printer, will appear as a `.prn` file which you can send to the actual printer later. (The disadvantage of this, however, is that you cannot display it on-screen, and your *actual* printer must support the exact same set commands as the one you installed. If Windows offers a PostScript printer driver, try it.)

Comment: Wouldn't the "print to file" be on the same list as the OneNote?  BTW I don't want to print the document... I just want to view the code that will be printed.  I appreciate the answer though @grawity

Comment: @wizlog: No, it would be a separate checkbox in the "Print" window, somewhere near the printer list. (Also, PostScript *can* be displayed on-screen by various programs, which is why I suggested it.)

Comment: Its not there.  There is no "print to file" check box...  Could it be that the description for my actual printer ports are "virtual printer port for USB"?

Comment: No, I'm sure it works for any kind of printer. What I'm *not* sure about is whether this feature still exists on Windows 7 :(

Comment: Thanks anyway.  I'll try other avenues... (ex. printing to thumb drive...)